# DropdownList com Modal

Tags: asp.net

boa tarde.
Tenho uma tela com uma grid feita em webforms, e ao clicar no botão existente na grid, é exibida uma modal com as informações do registro correspondente. Nesta modal tenho alguns dropdownlist ligados a tabelas.
Só que se coloco o evento OnSelectedIndexChanged não abre mais o modal. Alguém já passou por este problema?
Chamada do modal:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("$('#editModal').modal('show');");
            sb.Append(@"</script>");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "EditModalScript", sb.ToString(), false);
```

Aqui o código de criação do dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLEditReq" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLEditRec" style="width:340px"
                                            DataTextField="nome_usuario" DataValueField="id_usuario" ValidationGroup="DDL" AutoPostBack="True"
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlb_req"></asp:DropDownList>
```

E aqui o código da criação da modal:

```
 <div id="editModal"  tabindex="-1" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```